# DD-wrt DNSMasq and Apache virtual hosts

Tags: router, dns, dd-wrt, dnsmasq, virtual-host

I have changed my LinkSys `wrt54g` router's firmware to  `DD-WRT v24-sp2 (07/22/09) micro`. I'm trying to make local dns on the router to allow all machines on my LAN to be able to access my computer's Apache server virtual hosts by there domain name. I have the following data facts:

1. Router IP is `192.168.2.1`, subnet mask is `255.255.255.0`
2. My computer's IP is `192.168.2.31`
3. There is an Apache virtual host named: `cars.fox` and it is accessible from my computer as `http://cars.fox` by the help of hosts file

The following screen shot shows the settings that I have tried on `Serveices Tab` of the router's web configurations, my reference for that settings could be found [in this link](http://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html):

[image]

However, I could not able to access the virtual host from a machine on the LAN, a smart phone, as `http://cars.fox`

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution has two parts:

1. Adding the following line in "Additional DNSMasq options":

   `address=/cars.fox/192.168.2.31` and the current value of "LAN Domain" is "/"
2. Adjust the Apache virtual host settings `conf/extra/httpd-vhost.conf` from:

*Notice the internal loop IP -127.0.10.44-*

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.10.44:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/Users/user/path/to/cars/web"
    ServerName cars.fox
    ErrorLog "logs/cars.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

**To**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
        DocumentRoot "C:/Users/user/path/to/cars/web"
        ServerName cars.fox
        ErrorLog "logs/cars.log"
        ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
    </VirtualHost>
```

Then restart the Apache server, and reboot the router. Now any local machine in my LAN will be able to access `http://cars.fox` hosted on the Apache server on my computer.